# Error while filling string typed NA in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame column where I have float values and string type NA value. I need to replace these NAs with the mean using the following code.

```
trainTestJoin["col1"] = trainTestJoin.groupby("col2")["col1"].
     transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```

I am getting

```
TypeError: could not convert string to float: NA
```

I tried to convert to before filling it.

```
trainTestJoin["LotFrontage"].astype(float)
```

But it gives the same issue. How to solve this issue?

Comment: How does data-frame look like? whats the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Convert to numeric using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) which supports, via `errors='coerce'`, conversion to float `NaN` for non-convertible values:

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce')
```

Then use `groupby` + `transform` directly:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna(df.groupby('col2')['col1'].transform('mean'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply `replace`:

```
trainTestJoin['col1'] = trainTestJoin['col1'].replace('NA',np.nan)
```

And then simply:

```
trainTestJoin['col1'] = trainTestJoin['col1'].fillna(trainTestJoin.groupby('col2')['col1'].transform('mean'))
```

And now (after all):

```
print(trainTestJoin)
```

Is gonna be expected output.